# Use JPA Entities with Observer Pattern or use MySQL View?

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa, observer-pattern

I have JE66 Application with three JPA Entities. Each id is Generated.AUT. Here are the Entities:

1. **Campaign**(String name) /OneToMany CampaignInterval (bidirectional)
2. **CampaignInterval**(Date campaignStart, Date campaignEnd) /OneToMany CostInterval(bidir)
3. **CostInterval**(Date costIntervaStart, Date costIntervalEnd, double costIntervalCost)

The user can enter the data in a JSF Page Here is an example:

- Campaign Name: google ads
- CampaignInterval: [01.05.2012 / 31.08.2012]
- CostInterval 1:   [10.05.2012   / 20.05.2012/ 2000 €]
- CostInterval 2:   [01.08.2012   / 07.08.2012, 700 €]

The data is saved in MySQL Database CAMPAIGN, CAMPIAGN_INTERVAL and COST_INTERVAL. The Enduser would like to have a DAILY_COST Table in MySQL  with the Columns[CampaignName, DailyDate, DailyCost] For the example above. **The DAILY_COST Table would have 17 Rows**:

- Row 01 [google ads, 10.05.2012, 200 €]
- Row 02 [google ads, 11.05.2012, 200 €]
- Row ....
- Row 10 [google ads, 20.05.2012, 200 €]
- Row 11 [google ads, 01.08.2012, 100 €]
- Row ...
- Row 17 [google ads, 07.08.2012, 100 €]

**The question is how to create the DAILY_COST Table?**

Could I use the Observer Design Patter with a fourth JPA Entity (DailyCost) as ObserverClass that calculate and create [CampaignName, DailyDate, DailyCost] Or should I use MySQL view to create the DAILY_COST Table from the existing 3 JPA Entities tables?

I am new to MySQL and I do not know how to create a view :-). I am very grateful for each answer with maybe a Code view example or links for good tutorial.

Thank you very much